# Can not connect to elasticsearch container in docker

Tags: java, elasticsearch, docker

I'm trying to use the official elasticsearch image for docker and I followed [this guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html) but when I'm trying to connect to elasticsearch cluster I had an exception `NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available`

my code

```
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "docker-cluster")
                .build())
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));
```

To run elasticsearch container I used this command

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "http.host=0.0.0.0" -e "transport.host=127.0.0.1" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.2.2
```

and when I open the browser on `localhost:9200` the browser shows this text

```
{
  "name" : "J5oojcO",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "SfkgAJmaT_Sb3erfYUl7sQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.2.2",
    "build_hash" : "f9d9b74",
    "build_date" : "2017-02-24T17:26:45.835Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.4.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

docker logs

```
[2017-03-28T23:57:47,804][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
[2017-03-28T23:57:48,214][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [S5IAW08] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (overlay)]], net usable_space [54.8gb], net total_space [62.7gb], spins? [possibly], types [overlay]
[2017-03-28T23:57:48,216][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [S5IAW08] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2017-03-28T23:57:48,224][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] node name [S5IAW08] derived from node ID [S5IAW08lQvupW8s_e8btAQ]; set [node.name] to override
[2017-03-28T23:57:48,233][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] version[5.2.2], pid[1], build[f9d9b74/2017-02-24T17:26:45.835Z], OS[Linux/4.9.12-moby/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_92-internal/25.92-b14]
[2017-03-28T23:57:52,719][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [S5IAW08] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2017-03-28T23:57:52,719][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [S5IAW08] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2017-03-28T23:57:52,720][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [S5IAW08] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2017-03-28T23:57:52,721][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [S5IAW08] loaded module [lang-groovy]
[2017-03-28T23:57:52,721][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [S5IAW08] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2017-03-28T23:57:52,722][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [S5IAW08] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2017-03-28T23:57:52,722][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [S5IAW08] loaded module [percolator]
[2017-03-28T23:57:52,723][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [S5IAW08] loaded module [reindex]
[2017-03-28T23:57:52,723][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [S5IAW08] loaded module [transport-netty3]
[2017-03-28T23:57:52,724][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [S5IAW08] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2017-03-28T23:57:52,727][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [S5IAW08] loaded plugin [x-pack]
[2017-03-28T23:57:54,117][WARN ][o.e.d.s.g.GroovyScriptEngineService] [groovy] scripts are deprecated, use [painless] scripts instead
[2017-03-28T23:58:00,388][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] initialized
[2017-03-28T23:58:00,389][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [S5IAW08] starting ...
[2017-03-28T23:58:00,920][WARN ][i.n.u.i.MacAddressUtil   ] Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces; using random bytes: 53:a4:67:2d:77:c8:57:b6
[2017-03-28T23:58:01,073][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [S5IAW08] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2017-03-28T23:58:04,224][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [S5IAW08] new_master {S5IAW08}{S5IAW08lQvupW8s_e8btAQ}{4xwcEYRxTmi7-bRwYXHbYA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
[2017-03-28T23:58:04,293][INFO ][o.e.h.HttpServer         ] [S5IAW08] publish_address {172.17.0.2:9200}, bound_addresses {[::]:9200}
[2017-03-28T23:58:04,295][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [S5IAW08] started
[2017-03-28T23:58:04,444][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [S5IAW08] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
[2017-03-28T23:58:05,622][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [S5IAW08] license [c0268fbc-15ce-418c-aacc-5b9d7c3cbaf7] mode [trial] - valid
[2017-03-28T23:58:10,747][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [S5IAW08] [.monitoring-data-2] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], templates [.monitoring-data-2], shards [1]/[1], mappings [node, _default_, logstash, cluster_info, kibana]
[2017-03-28T23:58:11,017][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [S5IAW08] [.monitoring-es-2-2017.03.28] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], templates [.monitoring-es-2], shards [1]/[1], mappings [shards, _default_, node, index_stats, index_recovery, cluster_state, cluster_stats, indices_stats, node_stats]
[2017-03-28T23:58:11,598][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [S5IAW08] [.monitoring-es-2-2017.03.28/KmXIrx3-R-G_ngo8rfIcZA] update_mapping [cluster_stats]
[2017-03-28T23:58:11,852][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [S5IAW08] [.monitoring-es-2-2017.03.28/KmXIrx3-R-G_ngo8rfIcZA] update_mapping [node_stats]
[2017-03-28T23:58:22,105][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [S5IAW08] [.monitoring-es-2-2017.03.28/KmXIrx3-R-G_ngo8rfIcZA] update_mapping [cluster_stats]
[2017-03-28T23:58:22,192][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [S5IAW08] [.monitoring-es-2-2017.03.28/KmXIrx3-R-G_ngo8rfIcZA] update_mapping [indices_stats]
[2017-03-28T23:58:22,264][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [S5IAW08] [.monitoring-es-2-2017.03.28/KmXIrx3-R-G_ngo8rfIcZA] update_mapping [index_stats]
[2017-03-28T23:58:44,237][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [S5IAW08] [gc][43] overhead, spent [668ms] collecting in the last [1.5s]
[2017-03-28T23:59:14,284][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [S5IAW08] [gc][73] overhead, spent [306ms] collecting in the last [1s]
[2017-03-29T00:00:03,456][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [S5IAW08] [.monitoring-es-2-2017.03.29] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], templates [.monitoring-es-2], shards [1]/[1], mappings [shards, _default_, node, index_stats, index_recovery, cluster_state, cluster_stats, indices_stats, node_stats]
[2017-03-29T00:00:03,685][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [S5IAW08] [.monitoring-es-2-2017.03.29/FulovogFThmVCpL0RS99Hg] update_mapping [cluster_stats]
[2017-03-29T00:00:03,774][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [S5IAW08] [.monitoring-es-2-2017.03.29/FulovogFThmVCpL0RS99Hg] update_mapping [node_stats]
[2017-03-29T00:00:03,856][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [S5IAW08] [.monitoring-es-2-2017.03.29/FulovogFThmVCpL0RS99Hg] update_mapping [indices_stats]
[2017-03-29T00:00:03,909][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [S5IAW08] [.monitoring-es-2-2017.03.29/FulovogFThmVCpL0RS99Hg] update_mapping [index_stats]
```

health link

```
1490745899 00:04:59 docker-cluster yellow 1 1 3 3 0 0 3 0 - 50.0%
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

The official guide says that the image is built with X-Pack, so I tried to disable xpack security, and I succeeded to connect to elastic seacrh container using `127.0.0.1:9300`

Thanks.

Comment: What about the container logs, any indication that something went wrong?

Also, try the healthcheck URL:

`http://localhost:9200/_cat/health`

Comment: I updated my question @Toresan

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why the docs instruct to do that, but when you pass `127.0.0.1` as the transport host the binding is made only to that address, and therefore is not accessible outside the container.

Try to define the `transport.host` as `0.0.0.0` too, so it binds also to the container IP.

Comment: This is critical; thank you.  Additionally, I've found that when you do this you _must_ also make sure that the `client.transport.sniff` setting is set to `false` in your `TransportClient` or the original error will appear.  This is to my knowledge not documented anywhere.