# How can I connect to ElasticSearch running in the official Docker image using TransportClient?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

(First, I'm aware of [Can not connect to elasticsearch container in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073737/can-not-connect-to-elasticsearch-container-in-docker).  My problem remains.)

I am kicking the tires on ElasticSearch.

I've [run the official Docker image from the command line as described in the official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-cli-run), specifying the `cluster.name` as `elasticsearch` (the documentation claims that is the default, but inspection reveals it to actually be `docker-cluster` by default):

```
$ docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "http.host=0.0.0.0" -e "transport.host=127.0.0.1" -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" -e "cluster.name=elasticsearch" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.2
```

You'll note that I've [disabled the X-Pack security, following official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/security-settings.html#general-security-settings).

You'll note that I've exposed both port 9200 and port 9300.

The result of pointing a browser at http://localhost:9200/_cat/health is:

```
1498166019 21:13:39 docker-cluster yellow 1 1 3 3 0 0 3 0 - 50.0%
```

…which doesn't fill me with confidence, but that's what you get, I guess, when you run things by following the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/security-settings.html#general-security-settings).

At any rate, next, using Java, I've built the `Client` like so:

```
this.client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.builder()
                                          .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch")
                                          .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
                                          .build())
  .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));
```

You'll note I've specified `127.0.0.1` as the hostname (matching the `transport.host` property) and `9300` as the port (matching the exposed port).

Then I run: `this.client.prepareGet("argle", "bargle", "1").get();`.  I'm expecting to see some kind of "hey, dummy, `argle` doesn't exist" error.

Instead, this results in the dreaded:

```
NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{q00tH2RKTlCkXut03lYHOg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]]
```

What am I doing wrong?  What part of the official documentation is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official documentation wants you to set the `transport.host` Docker environment variable to `127.0.0.1`.  This needs instead to be set to `0.0.0.0`.

So to connect to the official ElasticSearch Docker image for testing purposes, you need to run it like this:

```
$ docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "http.host=0.0.0.0" -e "transport.host=0.0.0.0" -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.2
```

The cluster name will be—contrary to what the documentation tells you—`docker-cluster` (not `elasticsearch`).  So that means that—contrary to what the documentation tells you—you need to build your Java client like this:

```
this.client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.builder()
                                          .put("cluster.name", "docker-cluster")
                                          .build())
  .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));
```

**Additionally, you must *not* have `client.transport.sniff` set to `true`.**  If you set it to `true` with this configuration, you get the original exception.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, "xpack.security.enabled=false" was the solution.

```
elasticsearch:
  image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.1
  ports:
    - 9200:9200
    - 9300:9300
  container_name: elasticsearch
  ulimits:
    memlock:
      soft: -1
      hard: -1
  mem_limit: 1g
  environment:
    - cluster.name=docker-cluster
    - node.name=one
    - bootstrap.memory_lock=false
    - xpack.security.enabled=false
    - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    - network.publish_host=192.168.99.100
    - transport.publish_port=9300
  volumes:
    - /usr/share/elasticsearch/data

elasticsearch2:
  image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.1
  ports:
    - 9201:9200
    - 9301:9300
  container_name: elasticsearch2
  ulimits:
    memlock:
      soft: -1
      hard: -1
  mem_limit: 1g
  environment:
    - cluster.name=docker-cluster
    - node.name=two
    - bootstrap.memory_lock=false
    - xpack.security.enabled=false
    - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    - network.publish_host=192.168.99.100
    - transport.publish_port=9301
    - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=192.168.99.100"
    - "discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=2"
  volumes:
    - /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```